# Where is Android.mk supposed to be?

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

In the documentation for Android NDK, the following statement is present:

> The Android.mk file resides in a subdirectory of your project's jni/ directory [...]
>   http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html

I can interpret from this that an `Android.mk` file should be placed in `[project_path]/jni/[module_name]/Android.mk`, each module having its own specific `Android.mk` file since this is what differentiates it from the application wide `Application.mk` file, but when I execute `ndk-build` I get the following error message:

> Android NDK: There is no Android.mk under ./jni
>      Android NDK: If this is intentional  please define APP_BUILD_SCRIPT to point
>      Android NDK: to a valid NDK build script.

I gather from that I am supposed to create a single `Android.mk` file  alongside my `Application.mk` file or define `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT` in  `Application.mk` to point to a single `Android.mk` file. This contradicts the documentation and leaves me wondering why there is a need for multiple makefiles when `Android.mk` will contain the definitions for all modules anyway-that could just as well be placed in `Application.mk`.

Reading a couple of NDK sample projects I found out that, indeed, the `Android.mk` file is in the same directory as `Application.mk` and executing `ndk-build` on them seems to work.

What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

#### Expected project structure

```
<project>/
 |
 +-- jni/
 |    |
 |    +-- Android.mk
 |    +-- [Application.mk] (optionally)
 |    +-- main.c
 |
 +-- AndroidManifest.xml
```

According to a short guide from here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts

> 8. Create an Android.mk file in the jni/ directory of your project
> 9. ... compile your native code using the ndk-build
>
>    ```
>    $ cd <path>/<to>/<project>
>    $ <ndk>/ndk-build
>    ```

However, there is a way to define custom NDK project structures using `ndk-build` with arguments.

#### Plain structure

```
<mylib>/
 |
 +-- Android.mk
 +-- [Application.mk]
 +-- main.c
```

```
$ cd <mylib>
$ ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk
```

#### Android.mk vs Application.mk

> why there is a need for multiple makefiles when Android.mk will contain the definitions for all modules anyway-that could just as well be placed in Application.mk.

1. `Android.mk` is mandatory and `Application.mk` is not.
2. `Android.mk` contains module definitions and `Application.mk` describes architecture, compiler options, and other "global" options.
3. `Android.mk` is orthogonal to `Application.mk` by design. If `Android.mk` contains 3 modules, and `Application.mk` 2 ABIs (e.g. arm and x86), then NDK will build (3 * 2) artifacts.
4. Variables from `Application.mk` appears in `Android.mk`, so you can use, for instance, `APP_ABI` in `Android.mk` to link architecture dependent libraries.
5. There are complex projects with a lot of makefiles and keeping common options in `Application.mk` is a clean way.
6. But still `Application.mk` is just a design decision, it **could've been** done differently.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer at least some of your questions. You are right about the documentation being a little confusing. If you are using a single native module, indeed the Application.mk may seem redundant - but, there are a few things that can only be set by the Application.mk (you can look here: [Application.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html)). The Application.mk is meant for settings that apply for all modules, whereas the Android.mk is for specific module settings. Indeed, usually simple projects have a single Android.mk and it resides on the same folder as the Application.mk.

You can define where to put them, it also depends how you build your code - for example, if you are using a task for building ndk using 'ndk-build' and commandLine command, you pass the folder path as an argument. Usually, according to my experience, they reside under the jni folder.